# Database in somee host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-hosting

My ASP.net MVC 4 runs well on my local machine but failed to run on somee. Here is the error message `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.a_table'.`

Source error is  `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ToList()))`

I have changed the connection string in web.xml to match with that that somee provided me. Any idea to get me out of this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hmm... I also think the problem is with your connection string. Could you please kindly check it again? Plesae try to post your full error message on forums.asp.net.

Comment: I have rechecked the connection string. About your recommendation, it worths a try. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, please find the solution on forums.asp.net or you may try to ask somee.com support team. Maybe they can give the solution for you. :)